# Load an output of py_image rule to Docker

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I have defined a basic `py_image` rule in my `BUILD` file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//python3:image.bzl", "py3_image")
py3_image(
    name = "app_image",
    base = ":base_image",
    srcs = ["serve.py"],
    deps = [
       "@mi_proto//:proto",
    ]
)
```

How to make the result of this rule available in Docker? I would like to it in `docker images` or spawn a container by `docker run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load this into the local Docker registry, you can request a tar file from the target:

```
bazel build //:app_image.tar
```

This tar can then be loaded in to Docker via `docker load -i path/to/app_image.tar`

Alternatively, using `bazel run //:app_image` will also run the container.

There are more options for loading and running container images in the [rules_docker docs](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#using-with-docker-locally)